# WordPress + Timber + Twig i18n extension

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm trying to implement localization to a site I'm currently building. My goal is to use the i18n Extension for Twig since that's my template engine of choice.

However, when I'm adding the extension the site just crashes, screen gets white, and returning a 500 error code. Log says 408 timeout. In the same function where I'm adding the extension I also added another extension which works great. I have successfully installed the extensions via Composer. (https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html)

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my function.php

```
<?php
/**
* Timber starter-theme
* https://github.com/timber/starter-theme
*
* @package  WordPress
* @subpackage  Timber
* @since   Timber 0.1
*/

Timber::$dirname = array( 'templates');
/** Start Timber! */

class StarterSite extends Timber\Site {
    /** Add timber support. */
    public function __construct() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
    add_filter( 'get_twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
    parent::__construct();
}

function add_to_context( $context ) {
    $context['site'] = $this;
    return $context;
}

public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
    $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n() ); // This line breaks the site
    return $twig;
}
}

new StarterSite();
```

Comment: 500 error doesn't mean anything, check your logs for the **actual** error message and work from there.

Comment: Thanks, log just says ”408”. So its a timeout basically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with WordPress and Timber, you don’t need to use Twig’s i18n extension, as stated in the [Internationalization Guide](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/internationalization/) in Timber’s documentation:

> Twig has its own i18n extension that gives you `{% trans %}` tags to define translatable blocks, but **there’s no need to use it**, because with Timber, you have all you need.

This means that in your Twig templates, you can use all the functions that you’d normally use with normal WordPress templates. Here’s an example for a button.

```
<button>{{ __('Submit', 'my-text-domain') }}</button>
```

You can set up your theme for internationalization like you would in a normal WordPress theme. Follow the [Internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/) section in the Theme Handbook.

Set up your **style.css** with a text domain and a domain path:

```
/**
 * Theme Name: My Theme
 * Author: Theme Author
 * Text Domain: my-text-domain
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */
```

Then, WordPress will look for a **my-text-domain.pot** file in the **/languages** folder of your theme. You can generate that POT file with Poedit Pro. Poedit Pro will find the translations in your Twig file.

Comment: ,thanks, i understand it better now. But how do i actually git the data into the po/pot/mo files? i got poedit, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: There are various methods that you can use that are described here: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/internationalization/#generating-localization-files. If you use PoEdit, you need the Pro version to have Twig support.

Comment: Yes, i got the pro version. the problem is that i cant understand how one load a language file programattically. by a click on a button for example.

Comment: Alright. I updated the answer with more information. I hope that helps!

Comment: I have gotten that far. But what if i want to pass a twig-string to __? Like descibed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640006/translate-acf-field-that-renders-in-twig-template

Comment: Thanks alot. Almost got it to work now. Only thing is to actually change the language when clicking on a button for example..

Comment: Now I get it, you mean a language switcher. This is usually handled by the translation plugin you’re using. For example, MultilingualPress has a language switcher that you can include into your theme: https://multilingualpress.org/docs/create-custom-language-switcher/.