# Translate ACF field that renders in twig template

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm working on a site where i in twig renders content that gets set via ACF-fields. Currently i'm implementing translations and was wondering how i would do it since it not really strings, its twig.

Php file:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

$context['header'] = array(
    'title' => get_field('header_title')
);

Timber::render('/templates/index.twig', $context);
```

My template looks like this.

```
<header>
    {% if header.title %}
        <h1>
            {{ header.title }}
        </h1>
    {% endif %}
</header>
```

But for the translation tool (po files) want the syntax to be:

```
{{ __("string to translate") }}
```

So how can i instead pass in `{{ header.title }}` into that?

Comment: Hm, still struggling with this. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t pass the header title into `__()`. Only static strings that are written in your code are handled with gettext functions like `__()`. They [don’t work with variables](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#variables). If you have strings from the database, you **won’t** use string translation functions. Instead, you need a multilingual solution for WordPress.

Read the Codex page about [Multilingual WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) to get started. You’ll probably want to use a plugin if you want to have content that is pulled from the database translated. Among the popular ones are:

- [MultilingualPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/)
- [WPML](https://wpml.org/)
- [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/)